# Is there a 24hr time format for this plug in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

i have jQuery.ptTimeSelect plugin which appears to be good for my project.
What am not sure is f there is a 24hr time format for it because the example that i came across [http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html][1]

[1]: http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html only has 12hr time format.

below is a code snippet from the above site

```
$('input[name="time"]')
    .ptTimeSelect({
        containerClass: undefined,
        containerWidth: undefined,
        hoursLabel:     'Hour',
        minutesLabel:   'Minutes',
        setButtonLabel: 'Set',
        popupImage:     undefined,
        onFocusDisplay: true,
        zIndex:         10,
        onBeforeShow:   undefined,
        onClose:        undefined
    });
```

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here. What plugin are you using? What code have you written to instantiate the plugin? Do you have a working example of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the options use for 24h:

```
timeFormat: "HH:mm"
```

for 12h am pm:

```
timeFormat: "hh:mm"
```

Or use `H:i` for 24h and `h:i` for 12h

The exact options and format depend on your library/plugin, but mostly it's because of `h` and `H`.

```
data-options=\'{"mode": "timebox", "overrideTimeFormat": 24, "timeFormat": "H:i"}\'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Look Here for 24 Hours Jquery Time Format](http://www.olva.com.pe/infoweb/reporte_oficinas/librerias/Time/example/index2.html)